# Why is My iPhone's Lock Screen Wider than Usual? Serious iPhone issue

Tags: ios, hardware, iphone, screen

[image]
Today on my way home, I accidentally dropped my iphone with the back facing the ground from about 1.2 metres in the air. All other iphone functions are not damaged except for the screen. My phone has a password and therefore iTunes cannot access it. Also, the screen is damaged so I cannot see anything, and cannot key in the password for my iphone. No matter how hard I slided on the screen it's still the same when I takes the next screenshot. Could it be that the screen had already slided to the side, that's why I couldn't slide to unlock? Or has the touch screen broken down? So what can I do to solve this type of problem? Any reccommendations of iPhone controller (connection from USB only)? I have no budget at all and would not spend any money on this.

Comment: Hold the home button and power button, your device will perform a hardware reset. Please give the results after you've done that.

Comment: @Rob It didn't work

Comment: Did the device reboot? Please give more details, I cannot do anything with *it didn't work*

Comment: @Rob How would I know? I can't see the screen. But I heard the sound of the iPhone reconnecting with the computer

Comment: I would say that the touchpanel is broken too. There is no other simple answer for this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a software issue you can fix it resetting the phone back to factory defaults (just make sure you back up first).

If it's a hardware problem like the screen doesn't work or touchscreen is not responding to touches then there's no simple fix. You can only resolve this by repairing the broken hardware.